# Signal r client reconnection with the same connection Id

Tags: javascript, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub, signaling

i have a signalig issue in my app, im workin with signar R, some times my app lose the connection so and i try to reconnect. the problem is that i need to reconnect with my first connection id , but the server return another id for my new connection. this is my code

```
this.hubConnection.onclose(async () => {
  console.log(' Restart connection after 5 seconds.')
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await this.hubConnection
      .start();
  }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.

});
```

i want to have another session with my first connection Id , any help please.

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about the [connection lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) and as you can see, when your connection is dropped, you are starting a new connection, you are not reconnecting here.

What you can try is using the `.withAutomaticReconnect()`, so if connection is closed not by the user, it will try reconnect ***but not with the same connectionId***. This method is avaliable in the `@microsoft/signalr` package.

Comment: That's wrong, it wont have the same connectionID. There is no support for reconnecting with the same connectionID at this time. Also, you're pointing at the ASP.NET SignalR docs and talking about the ASP.NET SignalR Core client

Comment: @Brennan will edit  that. Then it is clear that reconnoitering with same connection Id is not possible with his implementation.